# How to load resources together (like /tasks?ids=1,2,3)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I load multiple resources within one request in Ember.js?

I'm loading all my projects and want to display a list of all tasks that are assigned to this project, like:

```
Project 1
  Task 1
  Task 2
  Task 3
Project 2
  Task 1
  Task 2
  Task 3
```

My route returns all projects... (I've set `tasks: DS.hasMany('task', {async: true})` in my project model):

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('project');
}
```

...and my templates shows them and their tasks:

```
{{#each project in projects}}
  {{project.name}}
  {{#each task in project.tasks}}
    {{task.status}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But now ember fires dozens of requests for each single task. I wonder how to group them, so Ember just have to make one request for all tasks of a project (something like `/tasks?ids=1,2,3`)?

I'm using Ember, Ember-Data, a Rails API-Backend and Ember's ActiveModelAdapter and ActiveModelSerializer.

That's how my API returns a single project (like `/projects/1`):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just forgot to add [`embed_in_root: true`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html) to my serializers.